# Create through association with multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, associations

This must be a pretty common situation but i can't figure it out:

I've got a polymorphic Comment model, a Post model and a User model. 
This is my association setup:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, I don't want either the commentable_id nor the user_id to be attr_accesible since I don't want them subject to mass assignment. I know the solution is to create the comment through association, but how can I do that for both the associations?

**Edit:**

Example:
I'm in a post and i want to create a comment. Let's say I have the user_id. The way to do that is:

```
@post.comments.create(user_id: 1, content: "bla bla")
```

This will work, but I have to make the Comment's user_id attr_accessible. I don't want to do that for security reasons... Is there a way to associate the comment and the user another way?

Thanks to all helpers!

Comment: i don't get what you are asking for. could you show an example where this is a problem?

Comment: I added an example to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need:

```
user has_many :posts
user has_many :comments, :through :posts

post has_many :comments
post belongs_to :user

comment belongs_to :user
comment belongs_to :post
```

User is the common entity for both posts and comments.  A user can comment on a post only if the post exists (hence the has_many_through relationship between user, comments and posts).  I think the rest of the relationships are pretty self explanatory.

example:

```
user.posts.create(<post params>)

user.posts.find(1).comments.create(<comment params>)

user.posts #retrieve all posts
user.posts.find(1).comments #retrieve all comments by a user on the first post
```

**Update**

To comment on a post not owned by a user:

```
post = Post.find(params[:id]) 
user.comments.create(post_id => post.id, <other params>)
```

**Update 2**

It's important to retrieve the post object to alter the underlying data.  You can add a new column to your posts table, say, key (generate a hex value) which has a one-to-one mapping with the post's id.  You can also modify your routes to display this key instead of the default post id.
i.e., change

```
/posts/:id, /posts/:id/edit
```

to

```
/posts/:key, /posts/:key/edit
```

Now, you can retrieve the post object using the key and perform whatever operations you want with it.  Your users won't be able to alter the url now to change the post id. To make it more robust, you can encrypt the key (checkout the [crypt gem](http://crypt.rubyforge.org/)), display the encrypted key in your routes and decrypt the key to fetch the right object.

To summarize, you'll still need to expose one attribute to uniquely identify your post object.

Comment: but what if a user comments on a post that he didn't generate? I couldn't use the user.posts.find in that case...

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i'm still not convinced. Is the line in your update possible without making Comment.post_id attr_accesible? Because that's the whole point of the question.